# how to solve this async and pg problem in python?

Tags: python, conda, anaconda3

I'm having trouble configuring my machine to run a project that uses anaconda, I've uninstalled all the programs, I've already installed pg, wheel, numpy, anaconda and PyGreSQL. But it always presents the error below inside the pg folder. Has anyone had this problem?

```
PS C:\fontes\dw-gpass> & C:/Users/Administrador/anaconda3/python.exe c:/fontes/dw-gpass/scripts/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/fontes/dw-gpass/scripts/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    import Gpass_sales_ota
  File "c:\fontes\dw-gpass\scripts\Gpass_sales_ota.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pg
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pg\__init__.py", line 3
    async,
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```